# Creating asp CheckBox with c# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create dinamically several asp check boxes in C# code behind with a specific class, but I am getting *input* elements without the class in a *span* element. Is this a normal behaviour of C#? My goal is to have all dynamically created checkboxes with same class in order to loop them afterwards and see if they are checked.
Here is my C# code:

```
                Label data_month = new Label() { CssClass = "button" };
                data_month.Text = month;

                Label data_year = new Label() { CssClass = "button" };
                data_year.Text = year;

                Label data_plan = new Label() { CssClass = "button" };
                data_plan.Text = plan;

                CheckBox del_check = new CheckBox();
                del_check.ID = id;
                del_check.Attributes.Add("class", "delcheck_data");

                TableRow trow1_ex = new TableRow() { CssClass = "button" };
                TableCell tcell1_ex = new TableCell();
                TableCell tcell2_ex = new TableCell();
                TableCell tcell3_ex = new TableCell();
                TableCell tcell4_ex = new TableCell();

                table1_data.Rows.Add(trow1_ex);
                trow1_ex.Cells.Add(tcell1_ex);
                trow1_ex.Cells.Add(tcell2_ex);
                trow1_ex.Cells.Add(tcell3_ex);
                trow1_ex.Cells.Add(tcell4_ex);
                tcell1_ex.Controls.Add(data_month);
                tcell2_ex.Controls.Add(data_year);
                tcell3_ex.Controls.Add(data_plan);
                tcell4_ex.Controls.Add(del_check);

            }
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table1_data);
```

When I execute the code I get the following:

```
    <tr class="button">
    <td><span class="button">1</span></td>
    <td><span class="button">2010</span></td>
    <td><span class="button">Реални данни</span></td>
    <td><span class="delcheck_data">
        <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_58" type="checkbox"
        name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$58"></span></td>
    </tr>
```

I am using master page and content pages if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set css class for a checkbox using **`InputAttributes`**

```
del_check.InputAttributes.Add("class", "delcheck_data");
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! It worked perfectly!